# ASP.net simulate browser back button

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on my ASP.NET web project using VS2010, C#, I'm inserting a hyperlink in my page, labeled as BACK, and I want it to act like browser back button, how should I implement it? what is the easiest way?
how should I set its navigateURL property?
thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
<asp:button id="backButton" runat="server" text="Back" 
OnClientClick="JavaScript:window.history.back(1);return false;"></asp:button>
```

Except that's a button, of course :-( (read the question, Steve)

Try

```
navigateurl="javascript:history.go(-1);"
```

Comment: thanks steve, but how can I have it in my hyperlink? how should I perform this javascript function using a hyperlink?

Comment: Either use the edit I made in the navigateUrl attribute or use this: `<asp:Hyperlink Runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"
onclick="javascript:history.go(1);return false;">BACK<asp:Hyperlink>`

Comment: thanks Steve, you saved me a great time! a short but fully helpful reply, have good luck

Comment: @SteveMorgan I was trying this but getting trouble in make this work properly, I have a series of screens to go back to not only 1 screen. Suppose I go like this A->B->C->D. Now I want back to work in reverse like D->C->B->A but it's working like, D->C->B->C->B and then it keeps on going round between B and C. Can you help please :( ..

Answer (score 14):

You don't need ASP.NET, just use this HTML/JScript code:

`<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a>`

Answer (score 1):

@Steve
Not sure how to comment on an existing answer but... I figured that I could just for kicks say that you could always make the "button" a "linkbutton":

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery, you can simply add `data-rel="back"` to your anchor-tag

```
<a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="back">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    Response.Redirect(prevPage);
}
```

or

```
<asp:button id="btnBack" runat="server" text="Back" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
 OnClientClick="JavaScript: window.history.back(1); return false;"></asp:button>
```

Comment: You'll lost the state of the page if you do it from server side _(using Response.Redirect)._ With Javascript though, the state is maintained

Answer (score -2):

something like this should do

```
<button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Students (your controller name here)", new { id = @Model.Student.Id })</button>
ANOTHER WAY
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Students" asp-route-studentId="@Model.StduentId" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Back to List</a>
```